# jQuery autocomplete retrieve data from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I have implemented jQuery autocomplete function for my web, which is working fine. But I want the result of the autocomplete to retrieve only the data of a particular person and not the complete database result.

Below is the jQuery for the autocomplete

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.product_desc').autocomplete({source:'functions/products.php?', minLength:2});
```

products.php

```
//Path for the databsae
<?php
include '../include/configuration.php';

if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) )
    exit;

$rs = mysql_query('select id,item_name,fk_vendor_id from item where item_name like "%'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']).'%" order by item_name asc ', $con);

$data = array();

if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['item_name'],
            'value' => $row['item_name']
        );
    }
}
else 
{
    $data[] = array(
        'label' => 'not found',
        'value' =>''
    );
}

// jQuery wants JSON data
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
?>
```

Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: If you want one record then set LIMIT 1 in your query or pass user id in your query.

Comment: Hi Ravi, I tried passing the user id but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post that query also?

Comment: @RaviHirani I have used $_SESSION[user_id] code in products.php which I have posted above. But the query does not work when I use that global variable.

Comment: I see no answer has been accepted yet so if you are interested, I made an alternative to jquery's autocomplete for getting results from a database:  http://rufushale.com/article.php?w=19

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".product_desc").autocomplete({
source: "functions/products.php",
minLength: 2,
select: function(event,ui){
    //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, Any text field having class `.search` the auto complete suggestion will works on server side in ajax.php file you need to return array as below:

```
$response = ['Computer', 'Mouse', 'Keyboard', 'Monitor'];
echo json_encode($response);
```

Here is sample code for auto suggest.

```
$(document).on('keyups','.search',function() {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                if (request.term != "") {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        method: "post",
                        data: {
                            name: request.term
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data != "") {
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    var name = item.name;
                                    return {
                                        label: name,
                                        value: name,
                                        data: item
                                    }
                                }));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            autoFocus: true,
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var name = ui.item.data;
                $(this).val(name);
            }
        });
    });
```